# mysql trigger after insert does not work

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called `test` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id int auto_increment primary key,
prefix varchar(1) not null default ('s'),
newid varchar(10) null);
```

I would like column newid to be combined values of column id and column prefix when inserting new values into table test. For example:

```
 id    prefix    newid
 1     s         s1
 2     s         s2
 ...
```

So i tried to create after insert trigger like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test 
AFTER INSERT ON test
for each row BEGIN
set newid = concat(id,prefix); 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But i got this error:

```
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'newid'
```

Please tell me what I need to fix to achieve the result needed.

Best Regards

Comment: can anyone help please?

Comment: The problem is caused by not placing NEW (`SET NEW.newid := ...`). Remember a couple of things: 0) `Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred.`. 1) `In a BEFORE trigger, the NEW value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column is 0, not the sequence number that is generated automatically when the new row actually is inserted.`. - [20.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: So is there anyway to achieve the result i want?

Comment: One option may be to emulate a sequence in MySQL, look for information about it.